# How to Filter Directory Contents?

Tags: directory

How can I filter directory contents to return the **highest numeric named** directory? For example, suppose `(directory-files "/some/dir")` returns:

> ("." ".." "4.03.0" "4.02.9" "archives" "config" "log")

How can I extract the string "4.03.0"?

I tried using `seq-remove` with a regexp based predicate, but could not get it to work. Suggestions and insights appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`directory-files`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Contents-of-Directories.html) accepts `match-regexp` argument:

```
(directory-files "my/path/to/dir" nil "^[0-9][0-9.]*$")
```

should return `("4.03.0" "4.02.9")` and you extract the first element of the list using functions [`first` or `car`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Elements.html).

If you really want to use [`seq-remove`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequence-Functions.html), you can do that too:

```
(seq-remove
 (lambda (s)
   (not (string-match "^[0-9][0-9.]*$" s)))
 '("." ".." "4.03.0" "4.02.9" "archives" "config" "log"))
==> ("4.03.0" "4.02.9")
```

Note that `^[0-9.]$` matches `"."` and `".."`.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. Does `directory-files` ensure descending ordering? If not, is there a way to extract the target string independent of directory list order (i.e. assuming no particular order)?

Comment: @Ari: You are welcome. Order is determined by the 4th argument to `directory-files`. If that is not your question, you should close this one and ask another one.

Comment: @Ari: emacs is self-documenting, so you can find out about a function by asking emacs about it: `C-h f directory-files` e.g. will tell you what the function does and what arguments it takes. There is a similar facility for variables. Just do `C-h ?` to get more information.